# Removing Sile Stone Countertop

Tags: kitchen-counters, demolition

I am in the process of having some counters replaced.  Any suggestions on how to remove the Sile Stone without damaging the cabinet?  Trying to determine if the extra cost of demolition is worth it.

Comment: I would presume that, like most countertops, it is secured from underneath...

Answer (score 1):

1. Score the caulk underneath the cabinet that runs along the cabinet frame. If sections of the countertop have been joined with silicone, make note of their position. Use caution lifting the countertop at these sections.
2. Pry the countertop loose with the pry bar and hammer. If you run into caulk or epoxy seam that's difficult to break loose, don't use excess force. Instead, use a utility knife to score the caulk or seam until you can safely use the pry bar. Continue prying the front of the countertop loose along its length.
3. Lift the front of the countertop as you side a furring strip between the countertop and cabinet, as close to the back as you can go. Lower the countertop onto the furring strip.
4. Push the front of the countertop down, breaking the caulk seal at the back of the countertop. If necessary, go under the cabinet and pry between the wall and the back of the countertop while a helper pushes down on the front. Gently lift the countertop off the cabinet and set it aside.

Answer (score 0):

Silestone is glued to the top of the cabinet. Depending on how much adhesive and the type used it may be very difficult to remove. No mounting hardware on the ones I have helped install (only 2 with the same contractor).